# Draw chat bubble in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

How can I draw bubble speech with path in Android?

I don't know how can I use `onDraw` method to achieve this or can I use shape drawable?
Any links or description can help me

Thanks for advance

---

I found this but still need completed rounded corner and custom background color.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(myPath[0].x, myPath[0].y);
for (int i = 1; i < myPath.length; i++) {
    path.lineTo(myPath[i].x, myPath[i].y);
}
path.close();
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: what about nicely designed nine-patch-drawable?

Comment: @pskink =>i cant use nine-path.i comment the reason on Aashish Bhatnagar answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for rounded corner use this

```
m_paintPath.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

    m_paintPath.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // set the paint cap to round too

    m_paintPath.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(12)); // set the path effect when they join.
```

and for custom background use this
i use it for gradient

```
m_paintPath.setShader(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,m_SpeechBubbleRect.height() ,
                m_GradientStarColor, m_GradientEndColor,Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly complex task you can go for the nine patch images they are scalable please let me know if you want such images along with your email id

Comment: i know but i cant use nine patch image,because i want set different back color for each user in same conversation,the user count maybe two or maybe twenty!i dont know how much image must be created!

Comment: see Drawable.setColorFilter, you can use it to make dozens of bubbles each different color

Comment: i use setColorFilter to change the color of an png image.but it didnt work. mydrawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.DST_ATOP);